# PHP How get and use name function from variable?

Tags: php, function, variables

```
$function = $_GET["function"];
        if(property_exists($this, $function )){
            echo $this->function(); // problem is here
        }
```

as we can see we get name function from $_GET and than we check exist function in this class. but we are get problem when we wonna print fucntion name, because we are not know how right print `$this->function()` from `$function`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Look into PHP's `call_user_func` http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: Either `echo $this->$function();` or use [call_user_func()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: thanks, I did not find it sooner (`$function()` and about func too). print the answer please. `$function()` will be better for my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you'll want to use `method_exists`, not `property_exists`. Then, you can use `call_user_func` to call the method:

```
$function = $_GET["function"];
if(method_exists($this, $function )){
    echo call_user_func(array($this, $function));
}
```

Comment: why i not should use `property_exists`? it function can check exist variables and functions in class.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think you are correct about that. Here's a quick test:  http://codepad.org/oTlEayZP

Comment: im sorry, as we can see now( in you example and manual php.net) function `property_exists` check exist property only, it function not check exist method in class. thank you!
P.S.: I regret, but my reputation not permit vote for answer.